# Black screen after updates + reboot

Tags: updates

I've installed the suggested updates today, as usual, and rebooted.
The boot progress is pending with a black screen, and I can't even switch to console with CTRL-ALT-F1.

Well, I managed to boot in recovery mode, I installed updates via console, it did not help much.

When I continue booting, I get a console login, when I type `startx`, I'll get an error:

`no screens found.`

Is this maybe the problem? If not, what else could I do to roll back the updates, or finding the reason?